# Substitute a string

Tags: vim

I have some string this format:

```
"User-Password":"aaaa","Calling-Station-Id":"bbbb","Eltex-AVPair":"cccc","h323-call-type":"dddd","Framed-IP-Address":"eeee","NAS-IP-Address":"ffff","Cisco-AVPair":["xpgk-request-type=gggg","xpgk-src-number-in=hhhh","xpgk-dst-number-in=iiii","xpgk-src-number-out=jjjj","xpgk-dst-number-out=kkkk","h323-gw-address=llll"],"Acct-Session-Id":"mmmm","User-Name":"nnnn","Called-Station-Id":"oooo","h323-gw-id":"pppp","Event-Timestamp":"qqqq","h323-conf-id":"rrrr","h323-call-origin":"ssss","NAS-Port-Type":"tttt","NAS-Port":"uuuu"
```

I need to transform it into

```
User-Password = "aaaa"
Calling-Station-Id = "bbbb"
Eltex-AVPair = "cccc"
h323-call-type = "dddd"
Framed-IP-Address = "eeee"
NAS-IP-Address = "ffff"
Cisco-AVPair = "xpgk-request-type=gggg"
Cisco-AVPair = "xpgk-src-number-in=hhhh"
Cisco-AVPair = "xpgk-dst-number-in=iiii"
Cisco-AVPair = "xpgk-src-number-out=jjjj"
Cisco-AVPair = "xpgk-dst-number-out=kkkk"
Cisco-AVPair = "h323-gw-address=llll"
Acct-Session-Id = "mmmm"
User-Name = "nnnn"
Called-Station-Id = "oooo"
h323-gw-id = "pppp"
Event-Timestamp = "qqqq"
h323-conf-id = "rrrr"
h323-call-origin = "ssss"
NAS-Port-Type = "tttt"
NAS-Port = "uuuu"
```

using vim.

So should be something like

```
:s/\,/\r/g|:s/^\"//g|(something_for_copying_Cisco-AVPair)|:s/\"\:/\ \=\ /g
```

It's four parts:

1. transform , into \r
2. delete ^"
3. copying Cisco-AVPair and delete square brackets
4. transform '":' into ' = '

I can make only write first and last part of these substitutions. How can I deal with others?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to do this with vim? `sed` is a better tool.

Comment: I copy this string from logs to new vim flie, then transform it, then use this file to make some radius-requests. If there is a way to solve my case with sed, it will be helpful.

Comment: Does that same string appear only once in the file or multiple times? Is its pattern unique?

Comment: Well, values in "" in output file can be the same in the some cases. But left side of output file (left from =) will be unique

Comment: Are you sure it's not JSON? In which case use `jq`

Comment: @roaima yep, it is json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a series of search/replaces.

```
:%s/,/\r/g
:%s/^"
:v/:/s/^/Cisco-AVPair":"
:%s/\v":\[?"/ \= "
```

which translates to

1. replace each `,` with a newline
2. remove all leading quotes
3. replace start of lines *not* containing a `:` with `Cisco-AVPair":"`
4. replace all `":["` with `= "`

Comment: Wow. Works great. I Also added

:%s/\]//

so it deletes also ] symbol.
Is there a solution, if there no only Cisco-AVPair, that need to be copied? For example, if string contains 

"something":[

then copy this "something"

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018552/vim-how-to-use-a-match-from-a-global-command-in-a-range-following-the-match) answer I received asking a similar question. It's doable but convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I found next solution for this task:

```
echo '' | jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p|[([$p[]|tostring ]|join(".->.") ),(getpath($p)|tojson)]|join(" = ")'|grep '^RAD_REQUEST\.\-'|sed -r 's/^[A-Z_]+\.\->\.//'|sed -r 's/\.\->\.[0-9]+//'
```

You should enter the request between quotes in order to make it work

Comment: Your command makes assumptions about the input document that is not reflected in the question.  For example, what is `RAD_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are transforming a JSON document (which you have modified for the sake of the question so that it's no longer a valid JSON document) into TOML.  The TOML that you show is not *quite* valid either as it contains duplicated keys.

Assuming that your original JSON object is

```json
{
  "User-Password": "aaaa",
  "Calling-Station-Id": "bbbb",
  "Eltex-AVPair": "cccc",
  "h323-call-type": "dddd",
  "Framed-IP-Address": "eeee",
  "NAS-IP-Address": "ffff",
  "Cisco-AVPair": [
    "xpgk-request-type=gggg",
    "xpgk-src-number-in=hhhh",
    "xpgk-dst-number-in=iiii",
    "xpgk-src-number-out=jjjj",
    "xpgk-dst-number-out=kkkk",
    "h323-gw-address=llll"
  ],
  "Acct-Session-Id": "mmmm",
  "User-Name": "nnnn",
  "Called-Station-Id": "oooo",
  "h323-gw-id": "pppp",
  "Event-Timestamp": "qqqq",
  "h323-conf-id": "rrrr",
  "h323-call-origin": "ssss",
  "NAS-Port-Type": "tttt",
  "NAS-Port": "uuuu"
}
```

You may convert this into TOML using a variety of tools, for example `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ or with `yj` from https://github.com/sclevine/yj.

With `yq`,

```bsh
yq -t . file
```

or with `yj`,

```bsh
yj -jt <file
```

In both cases, the resulting TOML document would be

```
User-Password = "aaaa"
Calling-Station-Id = "bbbb"
Eltex-AVPair = "cccc"
h323-call-type = "dddd"
Framed-IP-Address = "eeee"
NAS-IP-Address = "ffff"
Cisco-AVPair = [ "xpgk-request-type=gggg", "xpgk-src-number-in=hhhh", "xpgk-dst-number-in=iiii", "xpgk-src-number-out=jjjj", "xpgk-dst-number-out=kkkk", "h323-gw-address=llll",]
Acct-Session-Id = "mmmm"
User-Name = "nnnn"
Called-Station-Id = "oooo"
h323-gw-id = "pppp"
Event-Timestamp = "qqqq"
h323-conf-id = "rrrr"
h323-call-origin = "ssss"
NAS-Port-Type = "tttt"
NAS-Port = "uuuu"
```